# React native activeBackgroundColor/activeTintColor for custom sidebar

Tags: react-native, react-redux, react-navigation

I'm calling custom sidebar inside DrawerNavigator. I'm trying to set active tint color and active background color for selected menu.

```
const DrawerStack = DrawerNavigator(
{
    ProfileScreen: { screen: ProfileScreen },
    Home: { screen: DashboardScreen },
}, 
{
    contentOptions: {
      activeTintColor: "#e91e63",
      activeBackgroundColor : 'purple',
    },
    gesturesEnabled: false,
    swipeEnabled: false,
    contentComponent: SideDrawer
});
```

Comment: Code looks right, what's your question?

Comment: That's only work if I don't use custom sidebar call, but here I'm calling custom sidebar

Comment: @GouravKumar , I am also facing the same issue, How did you solve it?

Comment: I did it by custom condition over each menu, here is sidebar code https://file.io/9SUTPj

Comment: @GouravKumar, link is broken...

Comment: Get it from here https://www.dropbox.com/s/i7opsrbwgz4wsgt/index.js?dl=0

Answer (score 2):

1) Pass props to SideDrawer.

2) Use `props.navigation.state.routes[props.navigation.state.index].routeName`
to detect the current route in SideDrawer and apply styles accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure you can change the background color in the custom contentComponent. In the SideDrawer jsx have a parent View with a background color.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass `props` to your component. And extract  '**activeTintColor**' and '**activeBackgroundColor**' from `props`.

```
const DrawerStack = DrawerNavigator(
{
   ProfileScreen: { screen: ProfileScreen },
   Home: { screen: DashboardScreen },
}, 
{
 contentOptions: {
   activeTintColor: "#e91e63",
   activeBackgroundColor : 'purple',
 },
 gesturesEnabled: false,
 swipeEnabled: false,
 contentComponent: props => <SideDrawer {...props}/>
});
```

In **SideDrawer**

```
const SideDrawer = props => {
  let { activeTintColor, activeBackgroundColor } = props;

  return ( //your implementation
    <View
      style={{
        backgroundColor: activeBackgroundColor
      }}
    >
      <Text style={{ color: activeTintColor }}>Title</Text>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Comment: That's work but it's apply to all menu, not to selected menu (active screen)

Comment: here I upload, https://expirebox.com/download/de67b2f07b717c38c3b8eb16346fea16.html

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution to having to render a background color dynamically. its not the best because of code repetition but it works

```
<SafeAreaView>
<View style={styles.itemContainer}>
    <TouchableOpacity
        style={[styles.item, props.navigation.state.routes[props.navigation.state.index].routeName === 'Inbox'
        ? { backgroundColor: Colors.PRIMARY_GREEN }
        : null ]}
        onPress={() => {props.navigation.navigate('Inbox')}}
    >
        <Image
            source={require('../assets/img/white-inbox.png')}
            style={styles.icon}
            resizeMode={'contain'}
        />
        <Components.BodyText text={'Inbox'} style={styles.itemText} />
    </TouchableOpacity>
</View>
</SafeAreaView>
```